# Is it possible to run two different gearman client/worker on same port?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gearman

I have typical scenario, where I want to put two different worker in listening mode (trained using some data), and want to call from different client.

```
for(100 times)
    w1 (listening) <- c1 will call 
    result1
    w2 (listening) <- c2 will call 
    result2
    compare (result1 and result2)
```

w1,w2 are trained using machine learning algo, on **different data** so takes time complete their process. So they need to be kept in listening mode, could not bear starting every time.

I tried to run them on different port, 4730 and 4731. But i guess it work on only one port, 4730.

client :

```
class client_(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gm_client = gearman.GearmanClient(['localhost:4730'])    

    def callWorker(self, query):
        c_result = {}
        completed_job_request = self.gm_client.submit_job("db_worker", query)
        c_result =  completed_job_request.result
        c_result = json.loads(c_result)
```

worker :

```
def __init__(self):
    self.gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])
    self.gm_worker.register_task('db_worker', self.testClassifier)
    self.root_dir = os.getcwd()
    self.trainClassifier()
```

How to manage this scenario? let me know if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also run the gearmand server!
The Client/Worker library cannot be used to send directly messages from a client to the workers. The jobs are sent to the server, stored in in-memory queues and delivered to the corresponding worker when it becomes available.

4730 is the default port used by the gearmand server.

You have to download gearmand with apt-get or from https://launchpad.net/gearmand and start it.
The argument that you pass to the client and worker is the hostname and port of the server. The server uses the string passed to the submit_job and register_task (in your case "db_worker") to match the job and the corresponding workers.

This means that you can use the same server and port for both of your workers and you simply need to register them with two different function names.

You can have a look at the documentation at http://gearman.org/ but it's pretty bad... Here you can find the instructions to download and run the server: http://gearman.org/getting-started